# 'No Module named Tensorflow' error while running 'sh local_test.sh' command while running the deeplab code

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

I am trying to install Deeplab and run it on my machine. I am following [this](https://beerensahu.wordpress.com/2018/04/17/guide-for-using-deeplab-in-tensorflow/)

I am able to run the initial test 'python3 deeplab/model_test.py' but I am getting

> No module named Tensorflow

error while running the next step, `sh local_test.sh`

Tensorflow is installed on the machine and I have tried with different versions of tensorflow to verify any incompatibility issues. Please suggest on where have I gone wrong and what needs to be done to run it successfully.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ssindhu/models/research/deeplab/model_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

But tensorflow is installed on the machine:
`pip show tensorflow` has given me the below output.

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.13.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/ssindhu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, astor, numpy, protobuf, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, termcolor, grpcio, wheel, keras-applications, gast, absl-py, keras-preprocessing
Required-by:
```

Comment: Make sure you follow the appropriate tutorials for installing TensorFlow and the proper GitHub process for installing deeplab: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/installation.md

Comment: @JoeA, I believe that I installed all the dependencies as mentioned. I am able to run the quick test successfully, but not the pascalvoc_2012.

Comment: Hmmmm is Tensorflow installed throughout the system I would try and reinstall it following the proper documentation and same with the deeplab

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a virtual environment

```
pip install virtualenv
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Now make a new directory name it enviornments:

```
sudo mkdir enviornmrnts
```

Go into this directory (cd enviornments) and activate the environment

```
virtualenv project1_env
source project1_env/bin/activate
```

now do this:

```
pip3 install -U --user pip six numpy wheel setuptools mock
pip3 install -U --user keras_applications==1.0.6 --no-deps
pip3 install -U --user keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 --no-deps


wget "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.0/bazel-0.24.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh"

chmod +x bazel-0.24.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.24.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

check the bazel version by

```
bazel version
```

******************************** Installing Tensorflow******************************"

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

After this:

```
pip3 install -U tensorflow==1.8.0
```

To check your installation use this:

```
cd models/research
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
cd object_detection/
python3 builders/model_builder_test.py
```